# Gnosis Safe simu via Tenderly succeeds without signatures

Tags: gnosis-safe, tenderly

How is it possible that the Safe UI is able to simulate a call to `execTransaction` via Tenderly before collecting the signatures?

See [this simulation](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/67b37988-d06b-4a63-a719-b4eac3234c24), it succeeds even tho it only contains a single signature. It's a 2-of-4 setup, so it should fail with `GS020` for not having enough signatures.
[image: screenshot of simulation showing a single signature in the input]

I thought Tenderly executes transactions against the real contracts, but seems like some of my assumptions are wrong about the way Tenderly and/or Gnosis Safe works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tenderly it is possible to overwrite the contract storage for a simulation and that's what the safe interface does: it overwrites the threshold in storage to 1 and uses a `msg.sender` signature from one of the owners.

Comment: ok that makes sense, thx a lot 